# Circular Inclusion with templated functions in MinGW

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, mingw-w64

I'm currently working on a game engine called Papaya. I recently ran into a problem where I have to classes. `Scene` and `Entity`. In the `Entity` class a `Scene*` is stored so that the entity can access the Scene's registry for templated helper functions such as `GetComponent<T>()` among others. The `Scene` class also stores an `Entity` as the primary camera for the runtime. Because of this, the Scene class must include the header `Entity.h`. However, the Entity class doesn't necessarily have to include `Scene.h` header. I moved all of the non-templated functions in the `Entity` class to a source file and forward declared `class Scene;` within `Entity.h`. I figured that since the `Entity` functions are templated, `Scene` will be known by the time they are compiled. And it worked! But today when my friend tried to compile the repository with MinGW-64, it didn't. I know there are many ways of fixing the compilation errors and I'm not concerned with how to do that. I'm instead curious about which compiler is correct and why: MSVC or MinGW-64. Both compilers are using C++17 for the standard. I am also open to feedback if you feel my design is fundamentally flawed in some way shape or form. My current plan to fix the error is to not store an `Entity` in `Scene` and instead move it to a separate `SceneRenderer` class. Here is some code in case my breakdown wasn't clear:

Entity.h

```
#pragma once

class Scene;

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity() = default;
    Entity(Scene*, uint32_t);
    ~Entity();
    
    void Destroy();
    bool Valid();

    template <typename T>
    T& GetComponent() 
    {
         return m_Scene->m_Registry.get<T>(m_EntityID);
    }

    // Other templated functions...
private:
    Scene* m_Scene;
    uint32_t m_EntityID;
};
```

Scene.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Entity.h"
#include "String.h"

class Scene
{
public:
    Scene();
    ~Scene();

    Entity CreateEntity(const String& name = "Empty Entity");
    void SetSceneCamera(Entity e);

private:
    entt::registry m_Registry;
    Entity m_SceneCamera;
};
```

Both source files contain their respective implementations. This code will compile with Visual-C++17 but not with MinGW-w64! Thanks!

Comment: Once I remove all of the stuff that can't compile because it's missing, I can't reproduce the problem. This is often an issue with questions that lack a [mre].

Comment: I am currently compiling the library to see what the error my friend had was. Thanks for the feedback. I'll write something that is repoducable quickly

Comment: You'd probably have to put `Entity` and `Scene` into the same header; or else do something uncomfortable like defining `Entity::GetComponent` in `Scene.h`. The body of `GetComponent` needs full definition of `Scene` class. The reason it compiles with MSVC is that, until very recently, MSVC didn't implement two-phase name lookup in templates  (in violation of the C++ standard) - basically, it treated a template as a macro, parsed it just well enough to find the closing brace, and re-parsed the whole thing at the point of instantiation.

Comment: Another way to break the cycle: have a free-standing helper function like `template <typename T> T& GetComponentFromScene(Scene*, uint32_t ID);` You can forward-declare it in `Entity.h` and have `Entity::GetComponent` call it; and define it in `Scene.h`

Comment: I like that idea a lot. I just decided to keep the ID of the camera entity in ```Scene``` instead of keeping an actual ```Entity```. I appreciate that you were able to give an explanation too!